Equivalent estimation of ARMAX models of time series
Suppose I have an ARMAX model as follows:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ARMAX}
\begin{split}
    \ln{\epsilon_t}^2=\phi_0+&\sum_{i=1}^{p_1} \phi_i \ln{\epsilon_{t-i}^2}+\sum_{j=1}^{p_2} \phi_{p_1+j} u_{t-j}+\sum_{k=1}^{p_3}\beta_k x_{k,t-1}\\
    &+ \sum_{l=1}^{p_4} \gamma_{l}\mathbb{I}_{\{\epsilon_{t-l}<0\}} \ln{\epsilon_{t-l}^2} + u_t.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I am arguing that under certain conditions I can estimate the parameters in two-steps. First, I run the regression:
$$\ln{\epsilon_t}^2=\phi_0+\sum_{i=1}^{p_1} \phi_i \ln{\epsilon_{t-i}^2}+\sum_{j=1}^{p_2} \phi_{p_1+j} u_{t-j}+u_t$$
and get residuals, $\hat{z}_t$.
In the second step, I run the regression of residuals on the rest of the variables:
$$\hat{z}_t = \sum_{k=1}^{p_3}\beta_k x_{k,t-1} + \sum_{l=1}^{p_4} \gamma_{l}\mathbb{I}_{\{\epsilon_{t-l}<0\}} \ln{\epsilon_{t-l}^2} + u_t.$$
I argue that under the following orthogonality conditons two-step procedure will result in the same asymptotically equivalent result as the one-step procedure (fitting ARMAX directly). Those orthogonality conditions are as follows:

$\text{Cov}(\ln{\epsilon_{t-i}^2}, x_{k,t-1}) = 0 \quad \forall i = 1, \ldots, p_1; \quad \forall k = 1, \ldots, p_3$.
$\text{Cov}(\ln{\epsilon_{t-i}^2}, \sum_{l=1}^{p_4}\mathbb{I}_{\{\epsilon_{t-l}<0\}} \ln{\epsilon_{t-l}^2}) = 0 \quad \forall i = 1, \ldots, p_1; \quad \forall l = 1, \ldots, p_4$.
$\text{Cov}(u_{t-j}, x_{k,t-1}) = 0 \quad \forall j = 1, \ldots, p_2; \quad \forall k = 1, \ldots, p_3$
$\text{Cov}(u_{t-j}, \mathbb{I}_{\{\epsilon_{t-l}<0\}} \ln{\epsilon_{t-l}^2}) = 0 \quad \forall j = 1, \ldots, p_2; \quad \forall l = 1, \ldots, p_4$.

Could you please check the correctness of my reasoning?
